# Write Double to file as NS object in Swift

Tags: swift

I have an app which I have set up to save and load data. So far I have it set up to write two arrays to file as NSArrays. What I need to know is how to write a Double to file in the same way.
Here is the code I used to write it to file:

```
  func saveData(){

    let a = NSArray(array: array1)
    do {
        try a.write(to: fileURL)
    } catch {
        print("error writing amounts file")
    }

    let b = NSArray(array: array2)
    do {
        try b.write(to: fileURL2)
    } catch {
        print("error writing description file")
    }
```

I have tried setting it up the same way, with no success:

```
 let c = NSValue(value: totalDouble)
    do {
        try c.write(to:fileURL3)
    }catch {print("error writing total file")}

}
```

I have tried NSValue, NSNumber, etc. and get an error. I could put the double into an array and save it like that, but that seems to me to be pretty inefficient. I really don't know much about ObjectiveC or what NS objects are, so any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `NSArray` in Swift? Use a Swift array. Use Swift serialization and make things a lot simpler.

Comment: it's just how I learned how to do it. And alright, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know how to do it with `NSObject`'s, you'd use `NSData`:

```
import Foundation

var d: Double = 1.23456
let dataOut = NSData(bytes: &d, length: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: d))

do {
    try dataOut.write(toFile: "file.dat")
} catch {
    print("Today ain't my day!")
    exit(1)
}

guard let dataIn = NSData(contentsOfFile: "file.dat") else {
    print("Today really ain't my day!")
    exit(1)
}

let d2 = dataIn.bytes.load(as: Double.self)
assert(d == d2)
```

Of course, that's not the "Swift way" of doing things... but you only mentioned `NSObject`'s so far (`NSArray` and so on).

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to save a Double to file you need first to convert it to data (array of bytes):

**Xcode 11.3.1 • Swift 5.1**

```
extension Double {
    var data: Data {
        var bytes = bitPattern.littleEndian
        return .init(bytes: &bytes, count: MemoryLayout<UInt64>.size)
    }
}
```

And to convert your data back to Double:

```
extension Data {
    var double: Double {
        .init(bitPattern: .init(littleEndian: withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: UInt64.self) } ))
    }
}
```

---

Now you can write your Double data straight to disk:

```
let value = 2.9
let valueData = value.data

let documents = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let url = documents.appendingPathComponent("file.dat")

do {
    try valueData.write(to: url, options: .atomic)
    let loadedData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    let loadedValue = loadedData.double
    print(loadedValue) // 2.9
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```